An efficient way to implement a scheduled job that polls a 3rd party API and updates your database
I have a Spring boot app which has a scheduled job that runs every 1,5 seconds. Its goal is to fetch data from a 3rd party api, update the database with results (if needed) and repeat. The next api call should not start before the previous updates are finished.
For simplicity lets say the code looks like this
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 3000, fixedDelay = 1500)
public void loadUpdates() {
    List<Item> recentItems = apiClient.getUpdatesAfter(lastUpdateAt);

    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Item item: recentItems) {
        tasks.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                () -> handleItemUpdates(item),
                itemUpdateExecutor
        ));
    }

    // need to wait for all updates to finish
    CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
    
    doSomethingElseHere();
    
    saveTheLastUpdateTime();
}

public void handleItem(Item item) {
    ItemDetails details = this.apiClient.getDetails(item.getId());

    
    switch (item.getStatus()) {
       case 1:
        doOneTypeOfDbUpdates(item, details);
       break;
       case 2:
        doOtherTypeOfDbUpdates(item, details);
       break;
    }
}

@Transactional
public void doOneTypeOfDbUpdates(Item item, ItemDetails itemDetails) {
    updateOneTable();
    insertManyRecordsToAnotherTable();
    deleteSomethingFromThirdTable();
}

It worked fine in the beginning but now as the data amount grows this approach takes to much time.
Let's assume that the code of handling works fine and the db queries are optimal.
Edit: One item would cause various actions like another API call, inserts/updates into different tables in a transaction and/or databases, so doing bulk inserts of all the items is not possible from the received list is not really an option.
The question is how can this be done in a better way?
I have thought of replacing threads with a queue (rabbitmq) and process with multiple instances, but how to make sure that the next iteration will not start until all of the jobs are finished?
Any suggestions are welcome - Spring Integration, Apache Camel or any other solutions/frameworks/libraries/queues/etc.
Thank you in advance.

"Lets assume that ... the db queries are optimal." - I think that that assumption may be your problem.  You will get better performance by doing the database updates in batches.

@StephenC that is true, but the processing is complex and the question is more about how to do better parallel processing or how to approach the problem in general

Measure, figure out where the bottleneck is and then determine the cause of action. Adding threads to a problem like this might even make it worse due to contention on the DB side, or other IO parts. You might want to do something smarter with the list of Item you get and figure out if you can split those in other lists with common actions and execute those in bulk/batch. That would really improve performance.

I would add a "staging" table probably, where its the raw data fetched or normalized for consumption, then process those constantly (bonus if you have a unique key you can use to discard duplicate data), so your scheduled job is just adding changes to the staging table for you to process

I agree with what M. Deinum said. In any case as workaround you may use some lock strategy (e.g. shedlock library)

You say that data amount grows and the service can't keep up the 1.5 sec of total update execution time, you are already using threads, so single instance won't scale, it was good if you told that the amount of data is predicted and will not grow much, if this is the case, focus on vertical scale, you should always prefer the simplest solution.
If vertical scale has reached its limits, what you are looking for is a horizontal scale solution, one option is a master / workers architecture, in which the master node divides the problem into smaller tasks and distributes them among the available workers.
If a single call to API is done each 1.5 sec master / worker, one solution could be:

Have a master calls the api and distributes the tasks (each item) to the workers (Kafka could be a good fit here)
Each worker should acknowledge when task is received and it should update when the task is completed
Once all workers updates that their tasks are completed, you are ready to process a new job
Each worker might need to be fine tuned so they won't run a single task longer then 1.5 sec
Depending on the solution you will implement (polling / pushing tasks), you might need to have an event bus

Before you start developing, you have to ask yourself some questions:

How do you define a task, that should be small enough to be independent and won't need to refactored again in the future if it can't run fast enough for the constrains you define
Can I scale the service without having a master, there are many options to distribute work among workers.
What is expected from the worker if it calls an API and it has network issues
Can each worker be stateless (so you can distribute tasks in many ways: round-robin, least loaded etc..)
Do I want to have the ability to recover if the service (master/worker) unexpectedly fails
Search for an existing solution for your problem, any library or framework that supports your design

That is partial list of issues that needs to be covered in your system

you can use Spring Batch, for example you have two api call, you can create two steps in a Spring Batch job Step A will call first api and Step B call second api.
With the ability to group steps together within an owning job comes the need to be able to control how the job "flows" from one step to another.
For your usecase you can use Sequential Flow scenario job where all of the steps execute sequentially
Features

Transaction management
Chunk based processing
Declarative I/O
Start/Stop/Restart
Retry/Skip

Spring Batch docs

Just add boolean variable and check value before each iteration. When its true - there would be no further processing:
private boolean inAction;

@Scheduled(initialDelay = 3000, fixedDelay = 1500)
public void loadUpdates() {
    if (inAction) return;
    
    try {
    inAction = true;
    List<Item> recentItems = apiClient.getUpdatesAfter(lastUpdateAt);
    ...
    } finally {
      inAction = false; 
    }
}


We encountered a scenario where multiple pods were active, and we needed to ensure that a scheduled job ran only once across any one of the pods. Additionally, we wanted to prevent the next job from starting until the previous job execution was completed.
To address this, we implemented the kagkarlsson/db-scheduler, a persistent and cluster-friendly scheduler for Java. This scheduler utilizes a single database table to track future task executions. When a task execution is scheduled, the db-scheduler identifies it and ensures its execution. This approach allowed us to achieve the desired job execution control across multiple pods effectively.
